# How to attach video from Photos app to Gmail message

Tags: macos, photos, video, gmail

I'm using the new Photos app on OS X Yosemite. I've imported multiple photos and videos from my iPhone 5 and they are now in my Photos library.

I would like to attach one of the videos in my Photos app to a Gmail message. I've tried dragging the video from Photos to my Desktop, but I get the following error:

[image: Export Error]

I've also tried searching for the filename in Finder (IMG_2671.MOV), but that yields no results. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: The original file is inside the Photo Library, which is a package, you'll have to perform the search inside of it. I don't know why exporting the video gives an error.

Comment: You could also try selecting the video and exporting with cmd+e or via the file menu, which gives you more options.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Photos app keeps all photos, thumbnails, application settings and other image/video meta-data in it's own package file located at **~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary**. As such, you won't find the original images or videos in a normal Spotlight search.

Native OSX applications can present themselves to Photos as a compatible extension. You can see these when right-clicking on a photo or video and selecting *share*.

### Exporting the video from Photos

As gmail is not a native application with this capability (and a quick google search suggested no alternatives), you'll need to export the video and attach it manually.

Select the video in Photos and choose File -> Export

[image: Export Menu]

You can choose to export the video unmodified. However, as you'll be attaching the video to an email, you may want to choose **Export 1 Video** and select a smaller **Movie Quality** so the video will fit within gmail's attachment size limit of 25mb.

[image: Export Options]

Comment: [Reference](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?hl=en) for gmails attachment size limits.

Answer (score -1):

The (ludicrously roundabout and infuriating) solution that worked for me came from [a macrumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-do-i-select-or-drag-pictures-from-the-new-photos-app.1876858/#post-21209959):

> drag the picture(s) from Photos to your desktop and then upload with Gmail from there.

Trying to attach directly from Photos using my browser crashed Chrome multiple times. What a massive series of failures (or willful withholding of functionality?) by Apple: no file dialog, no Share to copy to clipboard, no Gmail option. The Photos team should be ashamed no matter how this came to be.

Answer (score -2):

it is much simpler than all that: in Photos open, select the picture, then CTL+Click on it, in the side menu that opens select "share", that lets you choose Mail: than it adds itself to a Mail that you can then write.